# How do I connect to PostGIS from QGIS using operating system authentication?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

In my enterprise environment we've got a few PostGIS instances and access to QGIS.  Access is all controlled via Active Directory.  How do I connect to a PG instance from QGIS using AD/operating system authentication?

Comment: I think first you may read the documentation in the link [here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/security.html)

Comment: Hi, this documentation only describes setting up PostGIS.  I have already set up PostGIS with AD group access.  I am looking at how to connect _from QGIS_ using operating system authentication.  Thanks